# how to get elements by name using jquery?

Tags: jquery, element

how to get html element by name using jquery without using id or class ? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Give an example of your HTML where you want to retrieve an object.  Are you asking about the "name" attribute when you save "by name"?

Answer (score 23):

It should be known that the only correct answers that have been given are the ones that included quotes around the attribute value, ie.

```
$("[name='value']")
```

It is a mandatory requirement to include quotes around the value, see: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

If you are using "name" in reference to the nodeName or "tag", then simply select by that string:

```
$("div")
$("a")
$("p")
$("input")
$("body")
```

Comment: +1 for "It is a mandatory requirement to include quotes around the value". This is especially important if the name is something like "files[]".

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
$('[name=thename]');
```

**Note:** For performance reasons, it's better to specify the tag name. So, if you're looking for images with a name of winter, you'll use this:

```
$('img[name=winter]');
```

Comment: @sasola: Why do you say that? I've got the fiddle to prove it: http://jsfiddle.net/EbwtP/

Comment: we always put value inside quotes :)

Comment: @sasola: That's inside your HTML markup, because you want to use xHTML, but in your CSS selectors it makes no difference (unless you have space inside your attribute value).

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you mean tag name or named attribute.  So here is both -

Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

or
Element Selector (“element”)

http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/

```
// name attribute selector
$('[name=whatever]').each(function(index) {
  alert(index);
  // and of course depending on your element utilize $(this).doSomethingCool
});

// tag name selector for all h1 tags
$('h1').each(function(index) {
  alert(index);
  // and of course depending on your element utilize $(this).doSomethingCool
});
```

Answer (score 4):

If you mean the name attribute, it's this:

```
$('[name="value"]')
```

If you mean the element name, then it's like this:

```
$('ul')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('tagName')...
```

for `<tagName />`

or

```
$('[name="attributeName"]')...
```

for `<input name="attributeName" />`

The jQuery selector works like a CSS selector.

Comment: this is to get the value `$('[name="attributeName"]').val();`or use serialize if you are collecting more than one inputs' values with the same name `$('[name="attributeName\[\]"]').serialize();`

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, you can use lots of things besides just id and class.  The [CSS3 selector specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) is full of other things you can use and jQuery even has some more things than this I believe.  For example, you can use tag type, attribute values, position in the hierarchy.  These are all valid jQuery selector objects:

```
$("div")
$("div span")
$("[name=nyName]");
$("div span [name=nyName]");
$("ul li [name=nyName]");
```

In many cases, you will get better performance with selectors based on tag types, id values and class names because many browsers support searching for those in native code.

Answer (score 1):

To get the value, we can use multiple attributes, one of them being the name attribute. E.g

```
$("input[name='nameOfElement']").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this:`$('div[name="element_name"]')`.

Or other element type like:

img:   `$('img[name="element_name"]')`

td:    `$('td[name="element_name"]')`
...

Answer (score 0):

get the element by its name like

```
$("div")
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LA22t/9/)