# How to get all “option” values in “select” by the name using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, html-select

I've seen many threads about getting an array of option value but they're all done by id. Unfortunately, my select field does not have a proper id. 
How can I get an array of all values in the select tag by the name using Jquery?

```
  <select name="groupa">
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>
    </select>
```

I'd expect a result like this:

```
[
   '1' => 'A'
   '2' => 'B'
   '3' => 'C'
]
```

p/s: I've tried some similar codes but did not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get elements by name using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248815/how-to-get-elements-by-name-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
    var arr = [];

    $("select[name='groupa'] > option").each(function() {
       //doSomething
       //e.g push to arr
       arr.push(this.value);
    });
    console.log(arr);
```

To get all values into an array you can do:

```
    var arr = $("select[name='groupa'] > option").map(function(){
       return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you. But can u play with .map() function, it'd be nice.

Comment: I adapted the answer. I hope this fits your needs.

Comment: Many thanks. It turns out the issue was caused by an another factor and my syntax was right. Anyway, you answer is correct.