# Try to export form result into single field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fill one hidden field with the results obtained from an HTML form. I have seen someone who suggests using Javascript and jQuery. I've tried to write some scripts using that language. This is the HTML form hosted in Formtools platform ([www.formtools.org](http://www.formtools.org)):

I tried many times and I'm going crazy, cause everything I've tried didn't work. Could someone help me?

Thanks

```js
<$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#formdatimarketing.php").continue(function() {
    var tipologia_auto = $("tipologia_auto[]").val();
    var alimentazione = $("alimentazione[]").val();
    var km_annui = $("km_annui").val();
    var mod_acq = $("mod_acq").val();
    var budget = $("budget_spesa").val();
    var rata = $("rata_mensile").val();
    var abitudini_acq = $("abitudini_acq").val();
    var componenti_famiglia = $("n_comp_famiglia").val();
    var hobby = $("hobby[]").val();
    var professione = $("professione").val();
    var asscociazione_categoria = $("ass_cat").val();
    var privacy = $("privacy_mkt_all").val;
    var giorno_pref_ricontatto = $("giorno_ricontatto[]").val();
    var orario_ricontatto = $("orario_ricontatto[]").val();
    var mkt = "";
    mkt = tipologia_auto + "," + alimentazione + "," + km_annui + "," + mod_acq + "," + budget + "," + rata + "," + abitudini_acq + "," + componenti_famiglia + "," + hobby + "," + professione + "," + asscociazione_categoria + "," + privacy + "," + giorno_pref_ricontatto + "," + orario_ricontatto;
    output = mkt;

    alert(output);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="formdatimarketing.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="ts_form_element_id" name="edit_submission_form">
  <input type="hidden" id="form_tools_published_form_id" value="12">
  <a name="s143"></a>
  <h3>Dati Marketing</h3>
  <table class="table_1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="0" width="798">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="180" valign="top">
          Segmento auto richiesto
          <span class="req">*</span>
        </td>
        <td class="answer" valign="top">
          <div class="pad_left">
            <input type="checkbox" name="tipologia_auto[]" id="tipologia_auto_1" value="tipologia_auto_1">
            <label for="tipologia_auto_1">Citycar</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tipologia_auto[]" id="tipologia_auto_2" value="tipologia_auto_2">
            <label for="tipologia_auto_2">Berlina</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tipologia_auto[]" id="tipologia_auto_3" value="tipologia_auto_3">
            <label for="tipologia_auto_3">Monovolume</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tipologia_auto[]" id="tipologia_auto_4" value="tipologia_auto_4">
            <label for="tipologia_auto_4">Veicolo commerciale</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tipologia_auto[]" id="tipologia_auto_5" value="tipologia_auto_5">
            <label for="tipologia_auto_5">Suv</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tipologia_auto[]" id="tipologia_auto_6" value="tipologia_auto_6">
            <label for="tipologia_auto_6">Cabrio</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tipologia_auto[]" id="tipologia_auto_7" value="tipologia_auto_7">
            <label for="tipologia_auto_7">Coupe</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tipologia_auto[]" id="tipologia_auto_8" value="tipologia_auto_9">
            <label for="tipologia_auto_8">Station Wagon</label>
            <br>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="180" valign="top">
          Alimentazione
          <span class="req">*</span>
        </td>
        <td class="answer" valign="top">
          <div class="pad_left">
            <input type="checkbox" name="alimentazione[]" id="alimentazione_1" value="alimentazione_1">
            <label for="alimentazione_1">Benzina</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="alimentazione[]" id="alimentazione_2" value="alimentazione_2">
            <label for="alimentazione_2">Diesel</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="alimentazione[]" id="alimentazione_3" value="alimentazione_3">
            <label for="alimentazione_3">Metano</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="alimentazione[]" id="alimentazione_4" value="alimentazione_4">
            <label for="alimentazione_4">GPL</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="alimentazione[]" id="alimentazione_5" value="alimentazione_5">
            <label for="alimentazione_5">Ibrido</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="alimentazione[]" id="alimentazione_6" value="alimentazione_6">
            <label for="alimentazione_6">Elettrico</label>
            <br>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="180" valign="top">
          Km annui percorsi
          <span class="req">*</span>
        </td>
        <td class="answer" valign="top">
          <div class="pad_left">
            <input type="radio" name="km_annui" id="km_annui_1" value="km_annui_1">
            <label for="km_annui_1">0-10.000 km</label>
            <input type="radio" name="km_annui" id="km_annui_2" value="km_annui_2">
            <label for="km_annui_2">10.000 - 25.000 km</label>
            <input type="radio" name="km_annui" id="km_annui_3" value="km_annui_4">
            <label for="km_annui_3">Più di 25.000 km</label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="180" valign="top">
          Modalità di acquisto
          <span class="req">*</span>
        </td>
        <td class="answer" valign="top">
          <div class="pad_left">
            <input type="radio" name="mod_acq" id="mod_acq_1" value="mod_acq_1">
            <label for="mod_acq_1">Contanti</label>
            <input type="radio" name="mod_acq" id="mod_acq_2" value="mod_acq_2">
            <label for="mod_acq_2">Finanziamento - Leasing</label>
            <input type="radio" name="mod_acq" id="mod_acq_3" value="mod_acq_4">
            <label for="mod_acq_3">Noleggio</label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="180" valign="top">
          Budget di spesa
          <span class="req">*</span>
        </td>
        <td class="answer" valign="top">
          <div class="pad_left">
            <div class="cf_option_list_2cols">
              <div class="column"> <input type="radio" name="budget_spesa" id="budget_spesa_1" value="budget_spesa_1">
                <label for="budget_spesa_1">Budget: 0 - 5.000 €</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="radio" name="budget_spesa" id="budget_spesa_2" value="budget_spesa_2">
                <label for="budget_spesa_2">Budget: 5.000 - 12.000 €</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="radio" name="budget_spesa" id="budget_spesa_3" value="budget_spesa_3">
                <label for="budget_spesa_3">Budget: 12.000 - 18.000 €</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="radio" name="budget_spesa" id="budget_spesa_4" value="budget_spesa_4">
                <label for="budget_spesa_4">Budget: 18.000 - 24.000 €</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="radio" name="budget_spesa" id="budget_spesa_5" value="budget_spesa_5">
                <label for="budget_spesa_5">Budget: 24.000 - 32.000 €</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="radio" name="budget_spesa" id="budget_spesa_6" value="budget_spesa_6">
                <label for="budget_spesa_6">Budget: 32.000 - 40.000 €</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="radio" name="budget_spesa" id="budget_spesa_7" value="budget_spesa_7">
                <label for="budget_spesa_7">Budget: 40.000 - 50.000 €</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="radio" name="budget_spesa" id="budget_spesa_8" value="budget_spesa_8">
                <label for="budget_spesa_8">Budget: 50.000 - 60.000 €</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="radio" name="budget_spesa" id="budget_spesa_9" value="budget_spesa_9">
                <label for="budget_spesa_9">Budget: 60.000 - 70.000 €</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="radio" name="budget_spesa" id="budget_spesa_10" value="budget_spesa_10">
                <label for="budget_spesa_10">Budget: 70.000 € o più</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="180" valign="top">
          Rata mensile
          <span class="req">*</span>
        </td>
        <td class="answer" valign="top">
          <div class="pad_left">
            <div class="cf_option_list_2cols">
              <div class="column"> <input type="radio" name="rata_mensile" id="rata_mensile_1" value="rata_mensile_1">
                <label for="rata_mensile_1">Rata = 150-200</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="radio" name="rata_mensile" id="rata_mensile_2" value="rata_mensile_2">
                <label for="rata_mensile_2">Rata = 200-300</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="radio" name="rata_mensile" id="rata_mensile_3" value="rata_mensile_3">
                <label for="rata_mensile_3">Rata = 300-400</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="radio" name="rata_mensile" id="rata_mensile_4" value="rata_mensile_4">
                <label for="rata_mensile_4">Rata = 400-500</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="radio" name="rata_mensile" id="rata_mensile_5" value="rata_mensile_5">
                <label for="rata_mensile_5">Rata = 500-750</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="radio" name="rata_mensile" id="rata_mensile_6" value="rata_mensile_6">
                <label for="rata_mensile_6">Rata = 750 o piu</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="180" valign="top">
          Abitudini di acquisto
          <span class="req">*</span>
        </td>
        <td class="answer" valign="top">
          <div class="pad_left">
            <input type="radio" name="abitudini_acq" id="abitudini_acq_1" value="abitudini_acq_1">
            <label for="abitudini_acq_1">Primo acquisto</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="abitudini_acq" id="abitudini_acq_2" value="abitudini_acq_2">
            <label for="abitudini_acq_2">1 - 3 anni</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="abitudini_acq" id="abitudini_acq_3" value="abitudini_acq_3">
            <label for="abitudini_acq_3">3 - 6 anni</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="abitudini_acq" id="abitudini_acq_4" value="abitudini_acq_4">
            <label for="abitudini_acq_4">6 - 10 anni</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="abitudini_acq" id="abitudini_acq_5" value="abitudini_acq_5">
            <label for="abitudini_acq_5">più di 10 anni</label>
            <br>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="180" valign="top">
          Numero di componenti del nucleo familiare
          <span class="req"></span>
        </td>
        <td class="answer" valign="top">
          <div class="pad_left">
            <input type="radio" name="n_comp_famiglia" id="n_comp_famiglia_1" value="n_comp_famiglia_1">
            <label for="n_comp_famiglia_1">Single</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="n_comp_famiglia" id="n_comp_famiglia_2" value="n_comp_famiglia_2">
            <label for="n_comp_famiglia_2">Senza figli</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="n_comp_famiglia" id="n_comp_famiglia_3" value="n_comp_famiglia_3">
            <label for="n_comp_famiglia_3">1 figlio</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="n_comp_famiglia" id="n_comp_famiglia_4" value="n_comp_famiglia_4">
            <label for="n_comp_famiglia_4">2 o più figli</label>
            <br>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="180" valign="top">
          Hobby
          <span class="req"></span>
        </td>
        <td class="answer" valign="top">
          <div class="pad_left">
            <div class="cf_option_list_3cols">
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" id="hobby_1" value="hobby_1">
                <label for="hobby_1">Golf</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" id="hobby_2" value="hobby_2">
                <label for="hobby_2">Vela</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" id="hobby_3" value="hobby_3">
                <label for="hobby_3">Tennis</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" id="hobby_4" value="hobby_4">
                <label for="hobby_4">Cucina</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" id="hobby_5" value="hobby_5">
                <label for="hobby_5">Cinema</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" id="hobby_6" value="hobby_6">
                <label for="hobby_6">Musica</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" id="hobby_7" value="hobby_7">
                <label for="hobby_7">Fitness</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" id="hobby_8" value="hobby_8">
                <label for="hobby_8">Basket</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" id="hobby_9" value="hobby_9">
                <label for="hobby_9">Calcio</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" id="hobby_10" value="hobby_10">
                <label for="hobby_10">Motori</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" id="hobby_11" value="hobby_11">
                <label for="hobby_11">Sci</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" id="hobby_12" value="hobby_12">
                <label for="hobby_12">Concerti</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" id="hobby_13" value="hobby_13">
                <label for="hobby_13">Motociclismo</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" id="hobby_14" value="hobby_14">
                <label for="hobby_14">Automobilismo</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" id="hobby_15" value="hobby_15">
                <label for="hobby_15">Test drive in pista</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" id="hobby_16" value="hobby_16">
                <label for="hobby_16">Teatro</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" id="hobby_17" value="hobby_17">
                <label for="hobby_17">Fotografia</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" id="hobby_18" value="hobby_18">
                <label for="hobby_18">Arte</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" id="hobby_19" value="hobby_19">
                <label for="hobby_19">Viaggi</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="180" valign="top">
          Professione
          <span class="req"></span>
        </td>
        <td class="answer" valign="top">
          <div class="pad_left">
            <select name="professione">
              <option value="professione_1">Impiegato</option>
              <option value="professione_2">Libero professionista</option>
              <option value="professione_3">Agente di commercio</option>
              <option value="professione_4">Imprenditore</option>
              <option value="professione_5">Medico</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="180" valign="top">
          Iscritto ad associazioni di categoria
          <span class="req"></span>
        </td>
        <td class="answer" valign="top">
          <div class="pad_left">
            <input type="radio" name="ass_cat" id="ass_cat_1" value="ass_cat_3">
            <label for="ass_cat_1">Confindustria</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="ass_cat" id="ass_cat_2" value="ass_cat_4">
            <label for="ass_cat_2">Confartigianato</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="ass_cat" id="ass_cat_3" value="ass_cat_5">
            <label for="ass_cat_3">Confagricoltura</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="ass_cat" id="ass_cat_4" value="ass_cat_6">
            <label for="ass_cat_4">Confcommercio</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="ass_cat" id="ass_cat_5" value="ass_cat_7">
            <label for="ass_cat_5">Forze dell'ordine</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="ass_cat" id="ass_cat_6" value="ass_cat_8">
            <label for="ass_cat_6">Ordine dei Dottori Commercialisti</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="ass_cat" id="ass_cat_7" value="ass_cat_9">
            <label for="ass_cat_7">Ordine degli avvocati</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="ass_cat" id="ass_cat_8" value="ass_cat_2">
            <label for="ass_cat_8">Ordine dei medici</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="ass_cat" id="ass_cat_9" value="ass_cat_10">
            <label for="ass_cat_9">Altri ordini professionali</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="ass_cat" id="ass_cat_10" value="ass_cat_1">
            <label for="ass_cat_10">Associazioni di volontariato varie</label>
            <br>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="180" valign="top">
          Privacy marketing
          <span class="req"></span>
        </td>
        <td class="answer" valign="top">
          <div class="pad_left">
            <input type="radio" name="privacy_mkt_all" id="privacy_mkt_all_1" value="privacy_mkt_all_1">
            <label for="privacy_mkt_all_1">Si</label>
            <input type="radio" name="privacy_mkt_all" id="privacy_mkt_all_2" value="privacy_mkt_all_2">
            <label for="privacy_mkt_all_2">No</label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="180" valign="top">
          Giorno preferito per il ricontatto
          <span class="req"></span>
        </td>
        <td class="answer" valign="top">
          <div class="pad_left">
            <input type="checkbox" name="giorno_ricontatto[]" id="giorno_ricontatto_1" value="giorno_ricontatto_1">
            <label for="giorno_ricontatto_1">Lunedì</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="giorno_ricontatto[]" id="giorno_ricontatto_2" value="giorno_ricontatto_2">
            <label for="giorno_ricontatto_2">Martedì</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="giorno_ricontatto[]" id="giorno_ricontatto_3" value="giorno_ricontatto_3">
            <label for="giorno_ricontatto_3">Mercoledì</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="giorno_ricontatto[]" id="giorno_ricontatto_4" value="giorno_ricontatto_4">
            <label for="giorno_ricontatto_4">Giovedì</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="giorno_ricontatto[]" id="giorno_ricontatto_5" value="giorno_ricontatto_5">
            <label for="giorno_ricontatto_5">Venerdì</label>
            <br>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="180" valign="top">
          Orario preferito per il ricontatto
          <span class="req"></span>
        </td>
        <td class="answer" valign="top">
          <div class="pad_left">
            <div class="cf_option_list_2cols">
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="orario_ricontatto[]" id="orario_ricontatto_1" value="orario_ricontatto_1">
                <label for="orario_ricontatto_1">09:00 - 10:00</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="orario_ricontatto[]" id="orario_ricontatto_2" value="orario_ricontatto_2">
                <label for="orario_ricontatto_2">10:00 - 11:00</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="orario_ricontatto[]" id="orario_ricontatto_3" value="orario_ricontatto_3">
                <label for="orario_ricontatto_3">11:00 - 12:00</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="orario_ricontatto[]" id="orario_ricontatto_4" value="orario_ricontatto_4">
                <label for="orario_ricontatto_4">12:00 - 13:00</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="orario_ricontatto[]" id="orario_ricontatto_5" value="orario_ricontatto_5">
                <label for="orario_ricontatto_5">13:00 - 14:00</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="orario_ricontatto[]" id="orario_ricontatto_6" value="orario_ricontatto_6">
                <label for="orario_ricontatto_6">14:00 - 15:00</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="orario_ricontatto[]" id="orario_ricontatto_7" value="orario_ricontatto_7">
                <label for="orario_ricontatto_7">15:00 - 16:00</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="orario_ricontatto[]" id="orario_ricontatto_8" value="orario_ricontatto_8">
                <label for="orario_ricontatto_8">16:00 - 17:00</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="orario_ricontatto[]" id="orario_ricontatto_9" value="orario_ricontatto_9">
                <label for="orario_ricontatto_9">17:00 - 18:00</label>
              </div>
              <div class="column"> <input type="checkbox" name="orario_ricontatto[]" id="orario_ricontatto_10" value="orario_ricontatto_10">
                <label for="orario_ricontatto_10">18:00 - 19:00</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="ts_continue_button">
    <input type="submit" name="form_tools_continue" value="Continue">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to give us more info than just "didn't work". What happened? What debugging have you done? Errors? Invalid data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get elements by name using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248815/how-to-get-elements-by-name-using-jquery)

Comment: FYI, I removed the PHP and SQL tags since the question/issue seem to only be about JavsScript (jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

use the id not the name of the input fields
e.g. `var tipologia_auto = $("#tipologia_auto_1").val();`

Comment: I've got a problem with this solution, because every radio button is different as follow: radio_button_1, radio_button_2, radio_button_3, etc. I haven't a unique ID.

Comment: you can check your radio buttons via ```$("#idOfRadioButton").attr("checked");``` --> true/false

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you! I need also to store these concatenated values into one field that will be saved into the MySql Database.